# Use javascript to get caption in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, caption

I'm building a new site and I need to have the caption of my bootstrap carousel [edit] under the carousel itself.

So I changed position of `.carousel-caption` to relative instead absolute so I can move them above the carousel.

Problem : I have specials arrows for my next and prev function of carousel, and if the caption are different in heigh between sliders my arrow moves too ...

I didn't know how to fix that only in css, maybe with javascript but I don't know how to get caption content for display it where i want.

[edit] JSFiddle who show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/1321/

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle showing the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/1321/ Here the JSFiddle who show the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to put text at position top. You can do it following way.

Check this fiddle once

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/1324/

I just updated following:

```
#myCarousel .carousel-caption{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: none;
    top: 0; 
    max-height: 30%;
}
```

If you want to change the position still you just need to update the `top or bottom` positions.

### Edit:

You can decrease the bottom to -30px or something.. so that caption will be at bottom of the image. 
And you should check the `overflow: hidden` for its parent elemets.

Comment: Sorry my bad i said above and it was under .. I'm looking for have caption under the carousel so no choice position must be in relative, or maybe get caption with Js.

Comment: @VivienLorithias  _caption under the carousel_ what is exatly mean by that.. its not problem with position absolute. you can place the element anywhere in the page using absolute.